# ReyclerView item list massive gaps between items

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have created a recyclerview layout. I have also created a relative layout to use as an item for the recycler view. However, there are gaps of one screen between each item in the recyclerview list.

I have tried changing the constraints and layout to even things out.

This is the XML file for the relative layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res  /android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/DescriptionTextr"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Chore:"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/description_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/DescriptionTextr"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/choretime"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/DescriptionTextr"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:text="Length to do chore:" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/length_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/description_text"
    android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/choretime"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

This is the output on the android device:

[image]

Comment: can you please add the complete item file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try changing your layout_height to wrap_content.

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/DescriptionTextr"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Chore:"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/DescriptionTextr"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/choretime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/DescriptionTextr"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:text="Length to do chore:" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/length_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/description_text"
        android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/choretime"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

or you can give some static height or wrap_content with some padding/margin if you want a little bit of distance between items.

This should fix your issue. Right now, since it is match_parent, each item is taking the height of the screen.

Comment: Hey, if my answer helped you, kindly upvote. Thank you for accepting it :)

Answer (score 1):

In the root of your adapter layout make sure you're applying:

- `layout_height="wrap_content"` for a Vertical RecycleView;
- `layout_width="wrap_content"` for a Horizontal RecycleView;

In your case your adapter layour have a `match_parent` the view will have the size of the RecycleView.

**Example:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

   ....
</RelativeLayout>
```